# How to store rows as belonging to a specific user?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I already have a `users` table which has `username` and `password`. What I want to do is each user have his own agenda of contacts, but those contacts are not registered users.

For instance, I will log in with username+password, and my agenda could look like:

```
grandma|grandma's phone number|grandma's address
mom|mom's email|
etc.
```

Someone else's agenda could look totally different. How should I implement the database?

Comment: You showed the expected result - good. But what are you actually getting?

Comment: No, the thing is I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Add your `user` table's primary key as a foreign key in your `contact` table, and then only show to a logged-in user the rows with a matching user ID.

Comment: I don't understand why I get so many downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you have a table just called Contacts, with a unique ID for each record. Then, you can store the name (grandma), the phone number (grandma's phone number) and the address (grandma's address) in each record. This way, all you have to do is reference 1 ID, and this same ID can be referenced by multiple users.

Comment: But I want other users to not be able to access other's contacts, only their own. I won't want others to know my grandma's details.

Comment: Okay, understandable. However, you could make a table called Agendas, which stores the ID of the User, and the ID of the contact, as well as a unique ID of its own. Each record would store a contact for a single user. So, if one user has two different contacts, you relate this user's ID to each of the two Contact IDs. That way, all you do is query the UserID in this Agendas tables to get all of the Contact IDs. Also, you could do it Yesian's way by just using the relating the UserID to the Contact Record. Either should work, but my way requires an extra table, while his is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Create contacts table with fields: contact_name,phone,address,email... and user_id to connect it with users table

Comment: Didn't think of putting the contact name in the table. Wow.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes your `Users` table has a unique ID for each user.
You can create a table called `Contacts` with the attributes `ID`, `UserID`, `Name`, `TelephoneNumber`, `Email`, ...
You can then join the two tables to see only a certain users contacts where the users ID matches the `UserID` field.

A query for what you want could be `SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE UserID=$ID` or if you want to select contacts by username, use `SELECT C.* FROM Contacts C INNER JOIN Users U ON C.UserID=U.ID WHERE U.username=$userame`